# Laravel routing not working, It shows URL NOT FOUND

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04, lamp

I have just created a Laravel 5.4 Project using Composer and set permission to `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` and `.env` file. Then set up virtual host say, `http://test_lara.com`. Then when try to get the project I am getting it fine. Then I added a new route in `web.php`

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

But I am not getting that URL I mean `http://test_lara.com/foo` when I try it I am getting "*URL not Found*".

Comment: So you can see default welcome screen on `http://test_lara.com/`?

Comment: Yes I can see the default welcome page

Comment: Tried `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Please check your route is created or not using `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: If you're using apache2 web server, check if `mod-rewrite` is enabled, and, anyway, all the mods required by laravel

Comment: Can you please share you vhost code? Is your DocumentRoot pointing to your-app-path/public folder?

Comment: Thanks all.. The problem was in virtual host set up Missed 'AllowOverride All'